# Azure Cloud Service Scaling - do I have to configure a Load Balancer?

Tags: php, load-balancing, azure-web-roles

I'm a little bit confused by how scaling in Azure works. I'm using a Cloud Service and have 2 web roles running a PHP application. I can RDP on both machines and both applications run great on each machine. Also I don't have any problems calling the staging URL.

But I can't figure out if I configure scaling so that 2 machines run always, if I have to configure a load balancer somehow. Or is this already done for me?

In Azure VM's I had to create a load-balanced set endpoint for an endpoint, but what about cloud services? [(Load balance virtual machines)](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balance-virtual-machines/)

And how is this done in the XML configuration file for my service? What if I don't do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered in the MSDN Forums:

> Windows Azure supports load balance for cloud services and standard websites, we just need to set instance count to more than 1 to enable load balance. For virtual machines, it needs to set up manually.

[Answer at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/c36f5008-f71a-4256-b2dc-357d43025308/azure-cloud-service-scaling-do-i-have-to-configure-a-load-balancer)